# why is my program not following given condition

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

i want to short when the candle is above ema and it's low and high should not touch the ema line . But the problem is it doesn't work when i exicute the code , why ?

[image: the bot takes short position on wrong candle]

`

```
 if  high[1]>ema and low[1]>ema and open[0]<=close[1]// bear
        strategy.entry("short3",strategy.short,100)
```

`

Comment: is low[1] less than high[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pinescript code is evaluated on each bar. 
By using high[1] and low[1] your are testing the bar before (= the first red bar on your chart = above the ema).
You should try :

```
if high > ema and low > ema and open<=close
    strategy.entry("short3",strategy.short,100)
```